# Template.FindName returns null while accessing control inside data template

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I am trying to access checkbox in my DataGrid's column header in code behind
but Template.FindName always returns null. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here ?

Here is my **Code Behind:**

```
   private void MyCheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var template = MyGrid.Template;
        var myCheckbox = (CheckBox)template.FindName("MyChkBxAll", this.MyGrid);
    }
```

**XAML:**

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="MyGrid" Margin="0,10,0,0" HeadersVisibility="Column" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="14" Width="280" Height="220" MaxWidth="700" MinWidth="200" Background="#FFF3F3F3" RowBackground="#FF37AEC9" AlternatingRowBackground="LightBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Center" CanUserAddRows="False"  KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="None" AutoGenerateColumns="True" GridLinesVisibility="None" IsReadOnly="True" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard" ColumnWidth="*" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" SelectionChanged="InstallableGrid_SelectionChanged">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Select" ElementStyle="{StaticResource  CheckBoxStyleInverted}" Width="Auto" >
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate x:Name="MyChkBx">
                        <CheckBox x:Name="MyChkBxAll" Style="{StaticResource  CheckBoxStyleInverted}" Margin="-3.2,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Checked="MyCheckBox_Checked" Width="50" Height="30"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You need to reference the `Select` column's `HeaderTemplate` instead I believe.

Comment: When i tried it like this  `var template = MyGrid.Columns[0].HeaderTemplate;` it throws an exception  "This operation is valid only on elements that have this template applied." I am also doing this `MyGrid.ApplyTemplate()`  before calling template.FindName